# React using onClick to send it to action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am trying to use onClick to send the two different state information to action event.

The user.user.user_id and post.book_id is from application state and I want to pass that information to action.

```
 <div 
      onClick={() => { this.props.addToMyPage({
                      user_id: user.user.user_id, book_id: post.book_id}) }}>
                Add this to my page
</div>
```

The part

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { selectBook } from '../actions/index';
import { addToMyPage } from '../actions/index';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
class BookDetails extends Component {
     componentWillMount() {
        this.props.selectBook(this.props.params.id);
    }
    render() {
        const {post} = this.props;
        const {user} = this.props;
        console.log("This Book", post)
        if(!post) {
           return <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        return (
            <div>

                <h1>Title: {post.title}</h1>
                <h2>Pages: {post.pages}</h2>
                <div>Reviews:</div>
                <div 
                    onClick={() => { this.props.addToMyPage(user.user, post) }}>
                    Add this to my page
                </div>

            </div>
        )

    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        post: state.books.post,
        user: state.user.post

    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {selectBook, addToMyPage})(BookDetails);
```

When I do this it only passes the user.user information and in the google console it says

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Not exactly sure what this means.
I have set up middleware in my index.js file.

//index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import reducers from './reducers';
import routes from './routes';
import promise from 'redux-promise';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

//action

```
export function addToMyPage(user, post) {
    console.log("mypage" , user, post);
    const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}api/mypage`, user, post);

    return {
        type: ADD_MYPAGE,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems more likely that the issue is with your `addToMyPage` action then with the code you posted. Make sure you either use something like `redux-thunk` for async actions or that you are returning a plain object in your action `function addToMyPage(user, post) { return { type: 'ADD_TO_MY_PAGE', user, post }; }`

Comment: I just added my action code.  I had everything till console.log("mypage, user, post) and commented the codes below that.  Is that the reason why it fired the plain object error?

Comment: Most likely that is why you got that error, actions have to return a plain object

Comment: Gotcha thanks for advice.  I was just testing it without the having return statement.  Good to know thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by  [Rob M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693275/rob-m) need to have object return in your action file.  I commented out the return object which threw the error.

```
  function addToMyPage(user, post) { return { type: 'ADD_TO_MY_PAGE', user, post }; }
```